# Populating a SelectList from a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I ran a query and returned a datatable,

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
```

Now what is the best way to load the row values "Value" and "Text" into a SelectList?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with it seems to work well, But I was wondering if this is the best way.

First I created an object that looks like my results form my query,

```
public class MyTestObj
{
    public string Value_CD { get; set; }
    public string Text_NA { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create a ILIST and populate it with the datatable rows

```
IList<MyTestObj> MyList = new List<MyTestObj>();
foreach (DataRow mydataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
  MyList.Add(new MyTestObj()
  {
    Value_CD = mydataRow["Value"].ToString().Trim(),
    Text_NA  = mydataRow["Text"].ToString().Trim()                      
  });
}

return new SelectList(MyList, "Value_CD", "Text_NA");
```

Any comments on this approach?

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't find a way to directly bind the DataTable to a SelectList so I resolved creating an Extension method to accomplish this:

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList(this DataTable table, string valueField, string textField)
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem() 
        {
            Text = row[textField].ToString(), 
            Value = row[valueField].ToString()
        });
    }

    return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    public static System.Web.Mvc.SelectList DT2SelectList(DataTable dt, string valueField, string textField){            
        if (dt == null || valueField == null || valueField.Trim().Length == 0
            || textField == null || textField.Trim().Length ==0)
            return null;


        var list = new List<Object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new
            {
                value = dt.Rows[i][valueField].ToString(),
                text = dt.Rows[i][textField].ToString()
            });
        }
        return new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(list.AsEnumerable(), "value", "text");
    }
```

I wrote this for u

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your DataTable has 2 columns (text and value), you have to

```
1. Set the DropDownList's DataSource to the table
2. Set the DataTextField to the text column name
3. Set the DataValueField to the value column name
4. Call the Databind method
```

Comment: forgot to mention I'm doing this in MVC and not using a control

Comment: ah, that's a very important piece of info. You might want to edit your post.

Comment: that's the asp.net approach not asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 2):

Datatable contains an extension method **AsDataView** . You can use this extension method to populate SelectList from a DataTable. A sample of code :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("1", "test");
//populate selectlist with DataTable dt
var selectList = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "Id", "Name");
```

Here **Id** in the **SelectList** is the **selectedValue** column and **Name** is the **DisplayMember** column.

Answer (score 1):

Completely in the line of 'Dot Net Developer' answer, I add my full implementation of his/her solution:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// retrieve the document types from the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SelectList FillDocumentTypes()
    {
        SqlCommand command = null;
        SqlConnection _sqlcon = null;
        SelectList result = null;
        try
        {
            _sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string commandText = string.Concat("select Code, [Description] from tblC2scDocumentTypeCodes");

            command = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlcon);
            _sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandText, _sqlcon);

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            //populate selectlist with DataTable dt
            result = new SelectList(dataTable.AsDataView(), "Code", "Description");

            _sqlcon.Close();
            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          }
        finally
        {
            command.Dispose();
            _sqlcon.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine.  I would make it a bit cleaner by creating a constructor for MyTestObj that accepted a DataRow.  That would allow you to write:

```
MyList.Add(new MyTestObj(mydataRow));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's way too late for me to answer but I think this might be an optimized way to do it, hope it works.

```
List<SelectListItem> listName= new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < datatableName.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
     listName.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = datatableName.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString(), Value = datatableName.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString() });
   }
```

You can also loop through the column names as well by applying another loop and using that as an index at the column identifier of the datatable.

Thank You.