# DropDownList in C# get only the first different row value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

This maybe a small problem but I really couldn't find out where it occurs.

I'm having a table of three columns which name is TaxRankID, TaxObjectID, and TaxName. In the controller code is like this:

```
    public ActionResult DefineFauna()
    {

        var cExtant = PredicateBuilder.True<FaunaPoliticalUnits>();
        cExtant = cExtant.And(r => r.PoliticalUnitLevel == 1);
        var results = from r in lw.PoliticalUnits.AsExpandable().Where(cExtant.Expand()).OrderBy(r => r.PoliticalUnitName)
                      select r;
        var selectList = new SelectList(results.ToList(), "GeogID", "PoliticalUnitName",5);
        this.ViewData["country"] = selectList;


        this.ViewData["tscope"] = ListHelp();

        return View();
    }

    private SelectList ListHelp()
    {
        var tsExtant = PredicateBuilder.True<FaunaTaxonomicScopes>();
        tsExtant = tsExtant.And(r => r.TaxRankID == 18 || r.TaxRankID == 17 || r.TaxRankID == 24);
        var tsresults = from r in lw.TaxonomicScopes.AsExpandable().Where(tsExtant.Expand()).OrderBy(r => r.TaxRankID).ThenBy(r => r.TaxName)
                        select r;
        var tsselectList = new SelectList(tsresults.ToList(), "TaxObjectID", "TaxName");
        return tsselectList;
    }
```

The first one, this.ViewData["country"] is working fine, creating a DropDownList like this:

```
<select id="country" name="country" style="width: 300;">
<option value="162">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="103">Albania</option>
<option value="82">Algeria</option>
<option value="4118">Andorra</option>
<option value="157">Angola</option>
```

The second one, which I've even moved it out as a separate function, looks exactly like the first one, but is producing weird results.

```
    <select id="tscope" name="tscope" style="width: 300;"><option value="12996">Neuropterida (all)</option>
<option value="12933">Glosselytrodea only</option>
<option value="12933">Glosselytrodea only</option>
<option value="12933">Glosselytrodea only</option>
<option value="12933">Glosselytrodea only</option>
<option value="12933">Glosselytrodea only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
<option value="12790">Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only</option>
</select>
```

Which, as you can see, are all the same. But I'm sure that in the database they are not the same,

```
TaxRankID   TaxObjectID TaxName
17  12996   Neuropterida (all)
18  12933   Glosselytrodea only
18  12922   Megaloptera only
18  12921   Neuroptera only
18  17137   Neuropterida, incertae sedis only
18  12923   Raphidioptera only
24  12790   Glosselytrodea : Archoglossopteridae only
24  12791   Glosselytrodea : Glosselytridae only
24  12380   Glosselytrodea : Jurinidae only
24  12262   Glosselytrodea : Permoberothidae only
24  12234   Megaloptera : Corydalidae only
24  12738   Megaloptera : Corydasialidae only
24  12280   Megaloptera : Euchauliodidae only
24  12911   Megaloptera : Nanosialidae only
24  12290   Megaloptera : Parasialidae only
24  12237   Megaloptera : Sialidae only
24  12811   Neuroptera : Aetheogrammatidae only
```

Looking like this. And it's clear that it's only choosing the first value of TaxRankID that's different.

Any ideas on why this happened?

Any help is appreciated.

---

I managed to generate the right DropDownList by using pure SQL and DataTable, however I'm still curious why the original one generates strange results.

If anyone should need, the modified code is pasted below, with thanks to Ryan VandenHeuvel's answer in [Populating a SelectList from a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439374/populating-a-selectlist-from-a-datatable)

```
        DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TaxRankID, TaxObjectID, TaxName FROM  lacewing.dbo.tblLdlFaunaTaxonomicScopes ORDER BY TaxRankID, TaxName", con);
        adapter.Fill(subjects);
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (DataRow row in subjects.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = row[2].ToString(),
                Value = row[1].ToString()
            });
        }

        return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: first of all why are you even using PredicateBuilder here when you are going to hard code all the values in the expression?

Comment: do you need only records with Id 17,18 and 24?

Comment: If you generate the actual SQL from LINQ in Visual Studio, or monitor the SQL, you'll probably find that it it's joining incorrectly to another table.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Well, the first code was someone else's, so I don't know why he used PredicateBuilder, I guess he used it all along in other parts of the code so just used it here.

Comment: @LucianBumb That part was not really necessary, I was just trying to see if I should add something to the tsExtant and it will work. Turned out it still won't work, though

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have only one table with this data format, so I guess it found the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your query like this:

```
    var ids=new List<int> {17,18,24};

    var results = lw.TaxonomicScopes.Join(ids, 
                  x => x.TaxRankID , 
                  y => y.TaxRankID , 
                 (x, y) => x)
                 .OrderBy(r => r.TaxRankID)
                 .ThenBy(r => r.TaxName)
                 .ToList();
```