# Trying to bind dropdownlist but getting error with the ToSelectList class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have issues when I try to use the `ToSelectList` class, I'm attempting to bind my SQL data to a dropdownlist, and have it displayed through a viewbag. But in the controller I get the error

> The name 'ToSelectList' does not exist in the current context

Here is the code of the action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newdbConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(constr);

    SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblCities", constr);

    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
    _da.Fill(_dt);

    ViewBag.CityList = ToSelectList(_dt, "CityId", "CityName");

    return View();
}
```

What have I tried?

I tried changing the code of the viewbag to...

```
ViewBag.CityList = new SelectList(_dt, "CityId", "CityName");
```

which only led to another error.

Comment: Prefixing variable names with underscore is normally a class level thing btw

Comment: What does the markup look like that renders the data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populating a SelectList from a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439374/populating-a-selectlist-from-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

The [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) component from MVC doesn't know how to deal with [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0) objects.

What you could do is:

1. To check if you can use the [AsDataView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asdataview?view=net-5.0) extension method.
2. To use the **DataTable.Rows** property (*_dt.Rows*, for your case)
3. Create a [*ToSelectList* function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050642/5641869) that gets the *DataTable* but returns an IEnumerable object (which is what *SelectList* expect)
4. Convert your data to a list based on your data model just like [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/).